# Correct prototype chain in console (with object inheritance)

Tags: javascript, prototype

Forgive me for being bothered by something that works, yet not showing up 'as expected' on the console.

Consider the following code:

```
function Person() {};
Person.prototype.PersonAction = function() {}

console.log( new Person() );
```

The console will show:

```
Person {PersonAction: function}
    __proto__: Person
        PersonAction: function () {}
        constructor: function Person() {}
        __proto__: Object
```

That's all good. Now consider this code:

```
function Mammal() {};
Mammal.prototype.MammalAction = function() {}

function Person() {};
Person.prototype = new Mammal();
Person.prototype.PersonAction = function() {}

console.log( new Person() );
```

The console will show:

```
Person {PersonAction: function, MammalAction: function}
    __proto__: Mammal
        PersonAction: function () {}
        __proto__: Mammal
            MammalAction: function () {}
            constructor: function Mammal() {}
            __proto__: Object
```

While this works (and I understand why it shows up this way), notice two prototypes of `Mammal`, with the top one having `PersonAction`. That's the bit I'm bothered by.

I wonder if there is any way to get this right, by 'right' I assume:

```
Person {PersonAction: function}
    __proto__: Person
        PersonAction: function () {}
        constructor: function Person() {}
        __proto__: Mammal
            MammalAction: function () {}
            constructor: function Mammal() {}
            __proto__: Object
```

Comment: I really don't think this is a bug. If the first example is correct (which I believe it is), then the second one is correct as well.

Comment: Oh yes, you were missing `Person.prototype.constructor`

Comment: In fact, you get the same thing if you deal with the constructor. It's the `Object.create` bit in jfriend00 answer that does the trick.

Comment: This seems rather weird, I'd assume DevTools would display either the object's `__proto__.constructor` property or retrieve the `name` property of function used to [`[[Construct]]`](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.2) the object. It does seem like a bug for it to display the wrong constructor after fixing it. Anyway, `Object.create` is recommended to avoid any instantiation side-effects (and somehow works around the problem).

Comment: Oh no wait, in the case of `ChildC.prototype = new ParentC();`, `(new ChildC()).__proto__ === ChildC.prototype` which is an instance of `ParentC`, that makes sense. You should care mostly about what is displayed in the first line: `Person {PersonAction: function}` indicates the object has been constructed by Person which is already correct in your case. Its prototype is an instance of Mammal, which is also technically correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it by setting the constructor back to what it's supposed to be and using `Object.create()` for the prototype:

```
function Mammal() {};
Mammal.prototype.MammalAction = function() {}

function Person() {};
Person.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);
Person.prototype.PersonAction = function() {}
Person.prototype.constructor = Person;

console.log( new Person() );
```

It gives you this in Chrome:

```
Person {PersonAction: function, constructor: function, MammalAction: function}
    __proto__: Person
        PersonAction: function () {}
        constructor: function Person() {}
       __proto__: Mammal
           MammalAction: function () {}
           constructor: function Mammal() {}
           __proto__: Object
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/CJF3L/

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, you set Person prototype with an instance of mammal and added a property personaction.

I assume personaction is not a constructor so it should not be capitalizes, its better to use object.create instead of creating an instance of parent to set the prototype part of inheritance.

More info here: [Prototypical inheritance - writing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711)