# JavaScript: prototype functions showing up in console

Tags: javascript

I just noticed that when I log an instance of the object I'm currently working on I see the prototype functions after it's property ( it only has one ). Which makes me think I'm doing something wrong.

[image]

This is how I'm setting the prototype.

```
MF = function(x){
    if(!(this instanceof MF)) return new MF(x);
    this.node = x;
}
MF.prototype = {
    show: function(display){
        display ? this.node.style.display = display : this.node.style.display = 'block';
    },
    hide: function(){
        this.node.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

console.log(MF(window));
```

I also tried setting it with `Object.create()`, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282628/correct-prototype-chain-in-console-with-object-inheritance), which doesn't make much sense in my case but desperate times call for desperate attempts.

Why am I seeing the prototype methods in the instance, and how can I fix this?

## EDIT:

For example here's how a `jQuery` object looks like, no prototype functions shown in the log

[image]

Comment: It's working for me.
MF
node: Window
__proto__: Object
hide: function (){
show: function (display){
__proto__: Object

Comment: Well I didn't say it wasn't working :/

Comment: It shows the functions under the prototype.

Comment: But why are they showing up after the property, I notice other native javascript objects don't behave this way, as well as jQuery objects, reference question edit

Comment: jQuery is array-like ***i.e.*** `*.prototype = []` but that's not what you want.  Does it really matter how the debugger represents the object? You can determine the properties belonging to the object itself with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` - is that not sufficient?

Comment: Which browser are you using?  The console output could vary from browser to browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing the prototype object it's a normal practice. And with jQuery this is also reproduced. Just call `console.dir($('div'))` and you will see `__proto__` object below. You can't hide prototype functions from console showing.

That's how I implement classes with prototype extending in my library:

```
Pinch.$ = function(selector, parent) {
    if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
        var callee = arguments.callee,
            newObject = Object.create(callee.prototype);
        callee.apply(newObject, callee.arguments);
        return newObject;
    }

    // --- logic ---

    return this;
}
Pinch.prototype = Object.create({
    is: function() {},
    // --- methods ---
    empty: function() {}
});
```

And then if you want extend your prototype with new methods:

```
Pinch.$.prototype = Pinch.Util.extend(Pinch.$.prototype, {
    newMethods: function() {}
}, {
    oneMoreMethod: function() {}
});
```

`extend()` realization you can find in many libraries and just googling "extend javascript"

The second way it's using `Object.create` as extend:

```
Pinch.$.prototype = Object.create(Pinch.$.prototype, {
    newMethods: function() {}
});
```

But really, you can't hide prototype object from console. Only if you will start using hacks and tricks based on local scope and more.

**UPD:** You can use `Object.defineProperties()` for hiding elements - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties

For example:

```
var MF = function () {};

MF.prototype = Object.create({});

Object.defineProperties(MF.prototype, {
    thisWillShow: {
        value: function () {},
        enumerable: true
    },
    thisWillNotShow: {
        value: function () {},
        enumerable: false
    }
});
console.log(new MF());
```

And working example here - http://jsfiddle.net/uRVFW/

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have no intention to *hide* prototype methods, I just thought it'd be nice if they didn't show up in the log of the instance. Not really something that matters, but.. `:D`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can hide them with ```Object.defineProperties()``` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties

Just use ```Object.defineProperties(MF, {})``` and set ```enumerable: false``` to needed methods that might to be hided.

Comment: A little working example - http://jsfiddle.net/uRVFW/

It still showing in console, but now you can enum this property in loops and other.

Comment: That's pure awesomeness right there! Now it has come to whether I should over-complicate code for the sake of good looks or leave it the way it is `xD` Thank you !!!

Answer (score 6):

There doesn't appear anything wrong with your code. I'm sure the prototype properties are only listed as a convenience when there are only a few instance properties. Expanding the logged object reveals that all properties are where they are supposed to be.

[image: chrome devtools]

Comment: Well that's a relief! But I still wonder how could I get rid of that convenience? I know it doesn't make any real difference but it's just bugging me from the inside, I guess you know that feeling :D

Comment: I know what you mean. Unfortunately, other than adding more properties, I don't have an answer for you. :(